# Create multiple files from one CSV, one files from each value in a column [Powershell]

Tags: powershell, csv, automation

I am new to PowerShell, and I have an issue figuring out how to create from one or multiple `.csv` files, one file for each value finding in a column, with all the rows that contains in that value.

Let me explain with a example:

I have this source CSV:

[image: Source Table]

I need to create a file for each App in the file. the output of the script should be something like this.

App1.csv

[image: App1.csv]

App2.CSV

[image: App2.CSV]

That for each app that appear in the Original CSV, a new file with all row that have such value, in this case App.

I want to do it in PowerShell so in can be automated, I try with Group-object, then foreach with the values, without luck. I wasn't even remotely close to found the solution.

Thanks in advance and happy coding!

Comment: In the source file, there is no App 2 in the Column Header 2. There is only 2 App1 data. In the output, you are showing 5 App1 data. Try to provide a correct sample for source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have the most elegant solution, but it works, I checked it on your files, but I ask you to upload the contents of the file as text next time to make it easier to copy. **And don't forget choose delimiter in code (I usually use ';')**

```
$some=Import-Csv "D:\testdir\file1.csv" -Delimiter ';'|
        Sort-Object header2|
          Group-Object -Property header2

foreach ($i in $some){
  $i.Group| 
    Export-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation -Force -Path ("D:\testdir\"+$i.Name+".csv")
}
```

Comment: Nicely done (I hope you agree that the reformatting makes the code more readable), though note that the `Sort-Object` call is unnecessary and only slows things down. (Also, if PowerShell's sorting weren't stable, you could end up changing the order of rows).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help, beautiful piece of code, i was able to complete the task taking out the -delimeter option, again thank a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Import the CSV.

Select all the unique values from the column that contains the App name.

Loop through the app names and get all rows where the app name matches.

Export to CSV.

```
$Path = "./MyFile.csv"
$DestinationDir = "./"
$CSV = Import-CSV -Path $Path

$AppNames = $CSV.H2 | Select -Unique

Foreach ($App in $AppNames)
{
    $DestinationPath = Join-Path -ChildPath $App -Path $DestinationDir 
    $CSV | Where {$_.H2 -eq $APP} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $DestinationPath
}
```

Example CSV:

```
H1,H2,H3,H4
Data,App1,Data,Data
Data,App1,Data,Data
Data,App1,Data,Data
Data,App2,Data,Data
Data,App2,Data,Data
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons, you probably want to use the [steppable pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.steppablepipeline?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) here:

```
$Pipeline = @{}
Import-Csv .\Source.csv |
    ForEach-Object -Process {
        if (!$Pipeline.Contains($_.Header2)) {
            $Pipeline[$_.Header2] = { Export-CSV -notype -Path .\$($_.Header2).csv }.GetSteppablePipeline()
            $Pipeline[$_.Header2].Begin($True)
        }
        $Pipeline[$_.Header2].Process($_)
    } -End {
        foreach ($Key in $Pipeline.Keys) { $Pipeline[$Key].End() }
    }
```

For a detailed explanation, see: [Mastering the (steppable) pipeline](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/mastering-the-steppable-pipeline/)